# Ninject, how to inject an object living in the session into my business class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, ninject

I have a profile object in session with profile information for the currently logged in user.  I wand to be able to inject it into my business classes so I can do validation etc in them without having to pass it in the parameter list in every method.

I have tried something like this in my ninject module:

```
Profile profile = HttpContext.Current.Session["Profile"] as Profile;
Bind<Profile>().ToConstant(profile).InTransientScope();
```

However it blows up with null reference when I do Kernel.Get() in my aspx.  The BusinessObject takes a profile via the constructor.  If I hard code the profile instead of using the HttpContext then everything seems to work.  Not sure if ToConstant is the way to go, I am really looking for something that will get evaluated every time a new BusinessObject is created.

**UPDATE**

It seems that asking for injection to happen on a page level object inline is too soon for the session collection to be available.  If I move in the Kernel.Get call to Page_Load it works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what's happening to your code is, at the time you're creating the binding, the Session profile is null.

You probably need to do something like this:

```
Bind<Profile>()
    .ToMethod(context => 
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Profile"] as Profile);
```

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Session seems to be null at the time .ToMethod runs.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on your BusinessObject constructor. Use the immediate window to evaluate HttpContext.Current.Session["Profile"] and see if your profile object is there. Also, ensure its type is Profile. If it's not there, then you might have some kind of other problem.

Comment: The problem is that HttpContext.Current.Session is null, meaning the entire collection is null.  I can easily get to HttpContext.Current.User, and that gives the the identity.  It's almost like the injection happens before the Session collection is somehow exposed.

Comment: You might need to examine when you're injecting your objects to make sure they coencide with the correct stage in the ASP.NET page life cycle. http://codebetter.com/blogs//images/codebetter_com/raymond.lewallen/89/o_aspNet_Page_LifeCycle.jpg

Comment: I don't see any event that has the word Session in it, but you are correct it had to do with that.  I moved this injection request into Page_Load that that solved the issue.  Clearly Session is not available when you request injection at a page level declaration.